# How do I "clone" a user account, i.e create an account using another account as default settings in Windows

Tags: windows, user-accounts, clone

Is there a way to create a new user account in Windows (Server 2008 R2 we are using, but Windows 7 would be much the same I'm sure) using another one for default settings? I.e. let's say I have an account called "Tom", with his own desktop icons, shortcuts, etc, could I make a new account called "Dick" that started off with all the same settings, desktop, quick launch, etc, as Tom has?

Comment: Do you know the C:\Users\default\ Folder?

Comment: Yes- maybe I should make more clear I want this to be a clone of an Administrators account and I don't want all users to have the same stuff, just this one particular users, and I don't want it to *stay* the same, just start off as a copy, that's all.

Comment: For such things I use User Profile Manager 2.1. I can't barely remember if they had an option for cloning an existing Profile to a new default User. I'll check it and give response as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [User Profile Manager 2.1](http://www.forensit.com/desktop-management.html) to copy an existing profile to a new default User Profile. It works in Windows 7 and lower to Windows XP. The Trial Version is free for 14 Days.

[image: Migration Window of User Profile Manager 2.1]