# How can I make multiple, new, templated user accounts (with custom prefs) on an existing system?

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, system-preferences

I have been using my Win10 (upgraded from 8.1) machine for a while now, accumulating a bunch of data in an account with admin privileges. I have resolved to start doing things properly, using limited accounts where possible; the thing is that I would like several such accounts so that I can organize separate "roles" for myself and manage identities more easily (for example, by keeping each user logged in with specific accounts on specific web sites).

Because I have so much data collected (and programs installed) already, I don't want to use `sysprep` or other such stuff (I also can't really understand what I looked up about these tools anyway). Instead, I would like to create several *new*, limited accounts, and *set each up in a consistent way ahead of time*. I have been playing around with a "test" account to figure out everything that I want to set up for a new user, and I have the following so far:

- Fix settings for default app usage
- Fix personalization settings (desktop theme, "This PC" etc. icons to appear on desktop, etc.)
- Fix privacy settings
- Configure Firefox
- Fix "Folder Options" preferences
- Relocate as many user folders as possible to D: (C: is a small SSD where the OS is installed; I want only essentials on here)
- Configure Start menu pins, taskbar contents and shortcuts (where does this Microsoft Edge desktop shortcut come from in each new user account I try making? It isn't on the Public Desktop!)
- Transfer files that each user should have from the admin account, depending on the user's "role" (this is the only part that I want to be different for each new account, at least initially)

Obviously this is a lot of work. For the theme I found that I didn't even have my admin user's theme offered as an *option* for the new account, until I exported and reloaded it as if I were transferring it between computers. Folder options, I had to work from screencaps to make sure I was setting everything the same way. I set up some default config stuff for Firefox that works well, but there are some things in `about:preferences` that don't seem to be configurable this way. etc. etc. It's all been quite frustrating just figuring out this test setup, without actually doing anything with it.

The question is: **How much of this can be automated, and how do I do it?** I wish I could just log in as the "Default User", make the changes, and have everything copied from there when new accounts are created; but it doesn't seem to work that way. (The Edge desktop links don't seem to come from there, either, FWIW.) Any hints? All I've been able to find here is [this previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/430444/how-do-i-clone-a-user-account-i-e-create-an-account-using-another-account-as) but that's long outdated.

Comment: What you describe requires the use of sysprep

Comment: Can I make that work without reinstalling Windows or moving my data back and forth to an external drive?